# Criar uma coluna que mostre percentual SQL

Tags: sql, int, porcentagem

Tenho uma query que busca 2 valores e quando dividido deveria retornar o percentual, porem esta com numero inteiro.

Acredito que erro esta aqui :

```
(COUNT(distinct neighborhood) / COUNT(distinct tbl.city)) as percentual
```

Como faço pra ela entender o valor do campo e nao da conta

```
SELECT 

city, 
neighborhood, 
count(neighborhood) as Soma_bairros,

(select count(city) FROM tb_listings WHERE city = tbl.city) as Soma_cidade ,

(COUNT(distinct neighborhood) / COUNT(distinct tbl.city)) as percentual

FROM tb_listings tbl

GROUP BY city, neighborhood 

ORDER BY city, neighborhood DESC
```

Resultado atual:

[image: Percentual retorna 100 e não 25 %]

Teria que classificar campo como INT ?

Comment: Qual o seu `SGBD`? Qual o tipo de dados das coluna `neighborhood`?

Comment: seria esse CREATE TABLE tb_listings (
  "advertiser_id" varchar,
  "listing_id" varchar,
  "portal" varchar,
  "city" varchar,
  "neighborhood" varchar);

Comment: Ah disfarça. Qual o `SGBD`?

Comment: A desculpe postgre, estou usando na ferramenta sql fiddle

Comment: Passa o link do fiddle então

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/1d25e/316

Comment: Ué, mas os dois lados da divisão dão 1, aí sempre vai retornar 1 mesmo. É melhor você explicar o que são seus dados e o que você quer extrair deles

Comment: Tire o neighborhood do group by , sempre vai dar 1 , multiplique por 100 para ter em percentual.